# Toggling an animation in CSS with jQuery, is there a better way than my solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to toggle a dropdown box that will appear and disappear upon clicking the button.

```js
var clickState = false;

$("#show").on("click", function() {
  if (!clickState) {
    $(".animated").removeClass("off");
    renewElement($(".animated"));
    $(".animated").addClass("on");
    clickState = true;
  } else if (clickState) {
    $(".animated").removeClass("on");
    renewElement($(".animated"));
    $(".animated").addClass("off");
    clickState = false;
  }
});

function renewElement(e) {
  var newElement = e.clone(true);
  e.remove();
  $(".container").append(newElement);
}
```

```css
.controls {
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
.textbox {
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
}
.animated {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: none;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.triangle {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent tomato transparent;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: -9px;
  margin-left: -7px;
}
.on {
  animation-name: slideOpen;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
.off {
  animation-name: slideOpen;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
@keyframes slideOpen {
  0% {
    max-height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <button id="show">Show div</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="animated">
    <span class="triangle"></span>
    <div class="textbox">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using a clickState boolean variable to keep track of the on and off presses, creating the toggle. I'm also cloning the entire div and recreating it so that the animation will refresh properly. The animation is connected to the element with the .addClass() method. I'm new to animation, but I can't help but feel I'm writing some really hideous code here.

Comment: Probably a better fit over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but I'm not good at where the line is at all, so...

Comment: Can use the classes applied to check state of an element also   ie `hasClass()`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined within the Help Center. Working code that simply needs a review might belong on Code Review, instead. As it stands, this question ("is my code hideous?") is primarily opinionated.

Comment: I'll go ahead and close it.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few potential issues that'll keep your solution from scaling to multiple elements on the page:

1. A global variable to keep track of the current state.
2. You animate all items at once using $(".animate");
3. Your unnecessarily clone and append the text. This could hinder performance on a large page.

Ideally, you simply toggle the applied classes, which introduces the animation.

```
$("#show").on("click", function() {
  var $animated = $('.animated');
  var shown = $animated.hasClass('on');
  $animated.toggleClass('on', !shown).toggleClass('off', shown);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I completely agree on point 1 and 2, it's not reusable at all in its current state. I am a bit confused on 3 though. While I absolutely hate the fact that cloning and appending are present in the code, it seems necessary for the animation to run again. The animation will only run once in your code example, on the first click.